# How do i listen to specific stream in bolt using apache storm and flux in yaml

Tags: apache, stream, apache-storm, flux

I have a bolt "XBOLT" . This will emit two streams( INTRESTED & ARCHIVED ) based on few conditions.

Then i have two bolts "YBOLT" and "ZBOLT" . Both of them are listening to XBOLT but on different streams . For example, YBOLT will listen to  ARCHIVED stream of XBOLT and ZBOLT will listen to INRESTED stream of XBOLT.

I have recently started using Flux with storm and trying to implement the above .

streams:

- name: "XBOLT --> YBOLT"
  from: "XBOLT"
  to: "YBOLT"
  grouping:
    type: SHUFFLE
- name: "XBOLT --> ZBOLT"
  from: "XBOLT"
  to: "ZBOLT"
  grouping:
    type: SHUFFLE

Now, in grouping section should i need one more field like "stream" ?, else how would it know to listen specific stream of XBOLT ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use another field to specify the name of the stream.
You can use the 'streamId' property inside the grouping section of your stream definitions.

for example in your case you can define streams like this:

```html
streams:
   - id: "XBOLT --> YBOLT"
     from: "XBOLT"
     to: "YBOLT"
     grouping:
       type: SHUFFLE
       streamId: "ARCHIVED"

   - id: "XBOLT --> ZBOLT"
     from: "XBOLT"
     to: "ZBOLT"
     grouping:
       type: SHUFFLE
       streamId: "INTRESTED"
```

For reference you can check the Stream and Stream Grouping section of this documentation. The documentation is for version 2 snapshot but it is working fine with my storm and flux version of **0.10.0**

http://storm.apache.org/releases/2.0.0-SNAPSHOT/flux.html

Answer (score 0):

The above answer is close, but it should actually be:

`streams:
   - name: "XBOLT --> YBOLT"
     from: "XBOLT"
     to: "YBOLT"
     grouping:
       type: SHUFFLE
       streamId: "ARCHIVED"`


   `- name: "XBOLT --> ZBOLT"
     from: "XBOLT"
     to: "ZBOLT"
     grouping:
       type: SHUFFLE
       streamId: "INTRESTED"`